# How to disable ALT+F4 on vb wpf Window

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a custom window that displays on errors or shows messages, depending on the context. How can I disable ALT+F4 to prevent a user from closing it, **without using events**.

The window needs to be closed only with a button that resides on it. I do not want users to be able to close it using ALT+F4. 
The main application can be closed using ALT+F4 and that is ok, but this Window should not be closed under any circumstances with ALT+F4.

Currently I have removed the window from being displayed in the taskbar.

Comment: The only why for this is using events. Why can't you use them?

Comment: So why if this is a VB app did you tag c#

Comment: @Smartis because MVVM

Comment: @BugFinder ty for noticing

Comment: @Nyalotha IMO it's these types of situations where the logic/code is really view oriented and one can drop the MVVM religion of no code in the view.

Comment: Alt+F4 is provided to your application through an event. Why can you not use events? That is a very strange and arbitrary requirement.

Comment: @kenny It's not me that is against events. It's just a requirement on this application.

Comment: @kenny thats a common misconception MVVM only requires that code in the code behind only deals with the view not that it doesn't exist, if you handle view logic in the VM you are breaking MVVM

Comment: there is something very wrong with your app if it "should not be closed under any circumstances" the users has final say over if an app can be closed or not, if your code requires this window to function then the first part of the logic should be if the window is closed open it

Comment: @MikeT I agree, it's a quite common misconception so that's why I brought it up. Saying it's part of the "religion" was overstepping, guilty ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XAML to catch Alt + F4.

```
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Modifiers="Alt" Key="F4" Command="{Binding Path=ToDelegateCommandThatExecuteNothing}" />
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

Create a RelayCommand in ViewModel like this :

```
public RelayCommand ToDelegateCommandThatExecuteNothing { get; set; }
```

Add method against ToDelegateCommandThatExecuteNothing and leave it blank or add whatever action you want to perform on Alt + F4:

```
ToDelegateCommandThatExecuteNothing = new RelayCommand(o => DoNothing());

public void DoNothing()
    {

    }
```

My code sample is in C#, you can check it for VB.Net